# Is there any way how to modify file during the require?

Tags: node.js, inject

I would like to modify code of library like inject some custom "code" during the require.

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = fs.readFileSync('./in').toString();
console.log(file)
```

So, I would like to modify function `readFileSync` from `fs` module. Is there any way how to inject `console.log('hi')` into `readFileSync` function and how?

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly known as the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). In short, you'd take the function and wrap it in another function that does *something else* plus the original behavior.

Example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
function myReadFileSync(...args) {
  // If you want the console.log before:
  console.log('will read file');
  fs.readFileSync.call(fs, ...args);
  // If you want a log after the real operation:
  console.log('managed to read the file');
  // (of course, you can have them both as well)
}
```

Then, use `myReadFileSync` instead of the original. This can usually be accomplished using [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) - you can inject functions just as well as you could inject objects as dependencies.

If the idea is to modify the "real" `fs` module, **don't**. This is an anti-pattern where you pollute the global namespace by altering default behaviors that the code relies on. It can be done in Node.js, but should only be undertaken if you know the consequences for your code. This is also a problem with some testing libraries such as Jest - they modify global objects, which is generally inadvisable.

Having said that, here's how apply this technique, which is called [monkey patching](https://www.audero.it/blog/2016/12/05/monkey-patching-javascript/):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
// We need to preserve the original implementation somewhere:
const realReadFileSync = fs.readFileSync;
fs.readFileSync = function myReadFileSync(...args) {
  // Same as in the decorator:
  realReadFileSync.call(fs, ...args);
};
```

It's best to read about it, evaluate the pros and cons, and decide whether this is what you want in your codebase.

Comment: `This is an anti-pattern where you pollute the global namespace` when done correctly the global namespace won’t be pollute.  `by altering default behaviors that the code relies on.` that for should not done.